# I just upgraded my Python Bokeh to 0.12.4 I get error JSON object has wrong type string

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

I just upgraded my Python Bokeh to 0.12.4 I get error JSON object has wrong type string.   I don't have any local static CDN libraries.  There is some info [here](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!msg/bokeh/l4rIoTim8Tk/jXTR65l2BAAJ) but it is confusing.  Does anybody have a simple answer for how to fix?

Note: my bokeh works fine in Jupyter.  It is failing in the Flask web embedding case here:

```
script, div = components(plot) return render_template('graph.html',
script=script, div=div)
```

where the graph.html template looks like this:

```
<link
    href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.4.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link
    href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-0.12.4.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-0.12.4.min.js"></script>

{{ script |safe }}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

i had same error in my django template, when was upgrading from bokeh 0.12.6 to bokeh 0.12.14, so i had added the same bokeh static requirements

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.14.min.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-0.12.14.min.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-tables-0.12.14.min.css" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.14.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-api-0.12.14.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-0.12.14.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-tables-0.12.14.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks!  Now that you mention it, I really feel dumb, because it was staring me in the face in the question itself:  I had 12.4 scripts in my template and I need 12.14.  I think it was the small cognitive distance between 12.4 and 12.14 that threw me off.